# Is there a convenient way to create Parcelable data classes in Android with Kotlin?

Tags: android, parcelable, kotlin

I'm currently using the excellent [AutoParcel](https://github.com/frankiesardo/auto-parcel) in my Java project, which facilitates the creation of Parcelable classes.

Now, Kotlin, which I consider for my next project, has this concept of data classes, that automatically generate the equals, hashCode and toString methods.

Is there a convenient way to make a Kotlin data class Parcelable in a convenient way (without implementing the methods manually)?

Comment: Did you tried kapt?  http://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2015/06/better-annotation-processing-supporting-stubs-in-kapt/

Comment: You mean to use AutoParcel with Kotlin? I thought about that, but if there was a way to have data classes Parcelable built in into the language, it would be beautiful. Specially considering a huge part of Kotlin usage will come from Android applications.

Answer (score 271, accepted):

[Kotlin 1.1.4](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2017/08/kotlin-1-1-4-is-out/) is out

Android Extensions plugin now includes an automatic Parcelable implementation generator. Declare the serialized properties in a primary constructor and add a @Parcelize annotation, and writeToParcel()/createFromParcel() methods will be created automatically:

```
@Parcelize
class User(val firstName: String, val lastName: String) : Parcelable
```

So you need to enable them adding this to you module's **build.gradle**:

```
apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.extensions'

android {
    androidExtensions {
        experimental = true
    }
}
```

Comment: For those who want to check it out: https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2017/08/kotlin-1-1-4-is-out/

Comment: why is this no longer data class. Is this example just to show that this could be applied on any generic kotlin class?

Comment: @NitinJain, if you read the link posted by @thalesmello, you'll see that this works on `data` and non-`data` classes.

Comment: compiler complains `this calss implements Parcelable but does not provice CREATOR field`. Is your answer enough (full)?

Comment: **Edited:** Ok compailer complains, but project Rebuild successfully, and after all it works.

Comment: @murt Did you successfully use Parcelable? I'm facing the compile error because of CREATOR

Comment: Yes, do everything in this answer and it will work. 

buildscript { ext.kotlin_version = '1.2-M2' ... repositories {... maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-dev/"}} dependencies {...
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }}

Comment: You can use `@SuppressLint("ParcelCreator")` to get rid of the lint warning.

Comment: I got a weird crash when using this feature, after leaving the activity that has it in one of its views: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method writeSerializable(Ljava/util/Date;)V in class Landroid/os/Parcel; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.os.Parcel' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar) . Seems it is still not stable : https://stackoverflow.com/q/46592138/878126

Comment: Be careful with @Parcelable, it may cause INSTALL_FAILED_UID_CHANGED errors https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/parcelize-causes-install-failed-dexopt-on-android-4/4662/2

Comment: Does this work fine now, with Kotlin version 1.2.10 ?

Comment: Don't Forget @Parcelize annotation on the top of class

Comment: How to pass array list via Intent putParcelableArrayListExtra ??

Comment: ...be forewarned, `These features are not considered production ready yet`; https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html

Answer (score 52):

You can try this plugin:

**[android-parcelable-intellij-plugin-kotlin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8086)**

It help you generate Android Parcelable boilerplate code for kotlin's data class. And it finally look like this:

```
data class Model(var test1: Int, var test2: Int): Parcelable {

    constructor(source: Parcel): this(source.readInt(), source.readInt())

    override fun describeContents(): Int {
        return 0
    }

    override fun writeToParcel(dest: Parcel?, flags: Int) {
        dest?.writeInt(this.test1)
        dest?.writeInt(this.test2)
    }

    companion object {
        @JvmField final val CREATOR: Parcelable.Creator<Model> = object : Parcelable.Creator<Model> {
            override fun createFromParcel(source: Parcel): Model{
                return Model(source)
            }

            override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<Model?> {
                return arrayOfNulls(size)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 37):

Just click on the data keyword of your kotlin data class, then press alt+Enter, select the first option saying `"Add Parceable Implementation"`

Comment: I used this method, but it has several problems. Sometimes it substitutes a `parcel.read...` with `TODO`, if a field is not `val/var`. If you use `List` inside a class, your implementation becomes a problem. So I turned to `@Parcelize` in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 29):

A simpler and up-to-date method would be to use the `@Parcelize` annotation which removes the hard word work of implementing the Parcelable

**build.gradle (app module)**

```
apply plugin: "kotlin-parcelize"

// If you are using the new plugin format use this instead.
plugins{
    ...
    id "kotlin-parcelize"
}
```

**YourClass.kt**

```
import kotlinx.parcelize

@Parcelize
class User(val firstName: String, val lastName: String, val age: Int): Parcelable
```

Answer (score 21):

- Use **@Parcelize** annotation on top of your Model / Data class
- Use latest version of Kotlin
- Use latest version of Kotlin Android Extensions in your app module

Example :

```
@Parcelize
data class Item(
    var imageUrl: String,
    var title: String,
    var description: Category
) : Parcelable
```

Answer (score 18):

Have you tried [PaperParcel](https://github.com/grandstaish/paperparcel)? It's an annotation processor which automatically generates the Android `Parcelable` boilerplate code for you.

**Usage:**

Annotate your data class with `@PaperParcel`, implement `PaperParcelable`, and add a JVM static instance of the generated `CREATOR` e.g.:

```
@PaperParcel
data class Example(
  val test: Int,
  ...
) : PaperParcelable {
  companion object {
    @JvmField val CREATOR = PaperParcelExample.CREATOR
  }
}
```

Now your data class is `Parcelable` and can be passed directly to a `Bundle` or `Intent`

**Edit:** Update with latest API

Comment: The IDE now says "Data class inheritance from other classes is forbidden". I think PaperParcel cannot be used anymore with data classes...

Comment: They never could inherit from other classes, but they can implement interfaces (e.g. PaperParcelable)

Comment: @Bradley Campbell  This gives me an error in this line  JvmField val CREATOR = PaperParcelExample.CREATOR cannot create  PaperParcelExample class

Answer (score 17):

The **best** way with **no boilerplate** code at all is [Smuggler](https://github.com/nsk-mironov/smuggler) gradle plugin. All you need is just implement AutoParcelable interface like

```
data class Person(val name:String, val age:Int): AutoParcelable
```

And that's all. Works for sealed classes as well. Also this plugin provides compile time validation for all AutoParcelable classes.

**UPD 17.08.2017** Now with [Kotlin 1.1.4 and Kotlin Android extensions plugin](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2017/08/kotlin-1-1-4-is-out/) you could use `@Parcelize` annotation. In this case, the example above will look like:

```
@Parcelize class Person(val name:String, val age:Int): Parcelable
```

No need for `data` modifier. The biggest downside, for now, is using kotlin-android-extensions plugin which has a lot of other functions that could be unnecessary.

Answer (score 6):

Using *Android Studio* and the *Kotlin* plugin, I found an easy way to convert my old Java `Parcelable`s with **no extra plugins** (if all you want is to turn a brand new `data` class into a `Parcelable`, skip to the 4th code snippet).

Let's say you have a `Person` class with all the `Parcelable` boiler plate:

```
public class Person implements Parcelable{
    public static final Creator<Person> CREATOR = new Creator<Person>() {
        @Override
        public Person createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Person(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Person[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Person[size];
        }
    };

    private final String firstName;
    private final String lastName;
    private final int age;

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName, int age) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.age = age;
    }

    protected Person(Parcel in) {
        firstName = in.readString();
        lastName = in.readString();
        age = in.readInt();
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(firstName);
        dest.writeString(lastName);
        dest.writeInt(age);
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
}
```

Start by stripping out the `Parcelable` implementation, leaving a bare-bones, plain, old *Java* object (properties should be final and set by the constructor):

```
public class Person {
    private final String firstName;
    private final String lastName;
    private final int age;

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName, int age) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
}
```

Then let the `Code > Convert Java file to Kotlin File` option do its magic:

```
class Person(val firstName: String, val lastName: String, val age: Int)
```

Convert this into a `data` class:

```
data class Person(val firstName: String, val lastName: String, val age: Int)
```

And finally, let's turn this into a `Parcelable` again. Hover the class name and Android Studio should give you the option to `Add Parcelable Implementation`. The result should look like this:

```
data class Person(val firstName: String, val lastName: String, val age: Int) : Parcelable {
    constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this(
            parcel.readString(),
            parcel.readString(),
            parcel.readInt()
    )

    override fun writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
        parcel.writeString(firstName)
        parcel.writeString(lastName)
        parcel.writeInt(age)
    }

    override fun describeContents(): Int {
        return 0
    }

    companion object CREATOR : Parcelable.Creator<Person> {
        override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): Person {
            return Person(parcel)
        }

        override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<Person?> {
            return arrayOfNulls(size)
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, the `Parcelable` implementation is some auto-generated code appended to you `data` class definition.

**Notes:**

1. Trying to convert a *Java* `Parcelable` directly into *Kotlin* will not produce the same result with the current version of the *Kotlin* plugin (`1.1.3`).
2. I had to remove some extra curly braces the current `Parcelable` code generator introduces. Must be a minor bug.

I hope this tip works for you as well as it did for me.

Answer (score 5):

I will leave my way of doing in case it might help someone.

What i do is i have a generic `Parcelable`

```
interface DefaultParcelable : Parcelable {
    override fun describeContents(): Int = 0

    companion object {
        fun <T> generateCreator(create: (source: Parcel) -> T): Parcelable.Creator<T> = object: Parcelable.Creator<T> {
            override fun createFromParcel(source: Parcel): T = create(source)

            override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<out T>? = newArray(size)
        }

    }
}

inline fun <reified T> Parcel.read(): T = readValue(T::class.javaClass.classLoader) as T
fun Parcel.write(vararg values: Any?) = values.forEach { writeValue(it) }
```

And then i create parcelables like this:

```
data class MyParcelable(val data1: Data1, val data2: Data2) : DefaultParcelable {
    override fun writeToParcel(dest: Parcel, flags: Int) { dest.write(data1, data2) }
    companion object { @JvmField final val CREATOR = DefaultParcelable.generateCreator { MyParcelable(it.read(), it.read()) } }
}
```

Which gets me rid of that boilerplate override.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it using `@Parcelize` annotation. It is an automatic Parcelable implementation generator.

First, you need to enable them adding this to your module's build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.extensions'
```

Declare the serialized properties in a primary constructor and add a `@Parcelize` annotation, and `writeToParcel()`/`createFromParcel()` methods will be created automatically:

```
@Parcelize
class User(val firstName: String, val lastName: String) : Parcelable
```

You **DONT** need to add `experimental = true` inside `androidExtensions` block.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there is no way in Kotlin to put a real field in an interface, so you can't inherit it from an interface-adapter for free: 
`data class Par : MyParcelable`

You may look at delegation, but it does not help with fields, AFAIK: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegation.html

So the the only option I see is a fabric function for `Parcelable.Creator`, which is kind of obvious.

Answer (score 3):

Below Kotlin code can help you to create Parcelable data classes with Parent and Child Data class

**Parent Data Class - MyPostModel**

```
data class MyPostModel(
    @SerializedName("post_id") val post_id: String? = "",
    @SerializedName("category_id") val category_id: String? = "",
    @SerializedName("images") val images: ArrayList<ImagesModel>? = null
) : Parcelable {
    constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this(
        parcel.readString(),
        parcel.readString(),
        parcel.createTypedArrayList(ImagesModel.CREATOR)
    )

    override fun writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
        parcel.writeString(post_id)
        parcel.writeString(category_id)
        parcel.writeTypedList(images)
    }

    override fun describeContents(): Int {
        return 0
    }

    companion object CREATOR : Parcelable.Creator<MyPostModel> {
        override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): MyPostModel {
            return MyPostModel(parcel)
        }

        override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<MyPostModel?> {
            return arrayOfNulls(size)
        }
    }
}
```

**Child Data Class - ImagesModel**

```
data class ImagesModel(
    @SerializedName("image_id") val image_id: String? = "",
    @SerializedName("image_url") val image_url: String? = ""
) : Parcelable {
    constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this(
        parcel.readString(),
        parcel.readString()
    )

    override fun writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
        parcel.writeString(image_id)
        parcel.writeString(image_url)
    }

    override fun describeContents(): Int {
        return 0
    }

    companion object CREATOR : Parcelable.Creator<ImagesModel> {
        override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): ImagesModel {
            return ImagesModel(parcel)
        }

        override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<ImagesModel?> {
            return arrayOfNulls(size)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

i prefer just using the https://github.com/johncarl81/parceler lib with

```
@Parcel(Parcel.Serialization.BEAN)
data class MyClass(val value)
```

Comment: This gives the error "Class 'MyClass' is not abstract and does not implement abstract member public abstract fun writeToParcel(dest: Parcel!, flags: Int): Unit defined in android.os.Parcelable

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin has made the entire process of Parcelization in Android damn easy with its @Parcel annotation.

To do that

**Step 1.** Add Kotlin extensions in your app module gradle

**Step 2.** Add experimental = true since this feature is still in experimentation in gradle.

> androidExtensions {
>       experimental = true
>   }

**Step 3.**  Annonate the data class with @Parcel

**[Here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-kotlins-parcel-makes-easier-pass-data-between-android-joshi/)** is an simple example on @Parcel usage

Answer (score 0):

There is a Plugin but is not always as updated as Kotlin is evolving:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8086

**Alternative:**
I have a working example of a custom data class using `Parcelable` and lists:

**Data classes using Parcelable with Lists:**

> https://gist.github.com/juanchosaravia/0b61204551d4ec815bbf

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody has mentioned this point ( Or rather, not provided specific detail on versions), I am going comment real quick on this:

I tried all the possible combinations of `@Parcelize` using the above guidance, but was not successful in getting it to work.

If your Android studio shows error on your class that `describeContents` or `writeToParcel` is not implemented, even with the `@Parcelize` annotation, please check that in your `app/build.gradle` you don't have `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'` enabled.

This is not working. For some reason, my project was using older deprecated version of extensions (**ktxVersion = '1.0.2'**).
So this was conflicting with the `@Parcelize` implementation.

When I tried to add `apply plugin: 'kotlin-parcelize'`, it said it's not going to work with the extensions simultaneously and I can have only one or the other.

After working with a colleague, we figured out that the extension was causing the whole `@Parcelize` to fail. I tried so many different things, but even after getting over the compile time errors, runtime error would say "CREATOR" not found exception or similar.

So finally I removed the *apply plugin* for `kotlin-android-extensions` and just included the `apply plugin: 'kotlin-parcelize'`, which fixed that issue, and it works as expected.