# Android Parcelable in Kotlin

Tags: android, parcelable, kotlin

I have such Java parcelable:

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {
    public KwerendaGraficzna createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new KwerendaGraficzna(in);
    }

    public KwerendaGraficzna[] newArray(int size) {
        return new KwerendaGraficzna[size];
    }
};
```

Now trying to implement it in Kotlin:

```
companion object {
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    val CREATOR: Parcelable.Creator<KwerendaGraficzna!> = object : Parcelable.Creator<KwerendaGraficzna!> {
        override fun createFromParcel(`in`: Parcel): KwerendaGraficzna {
            return KwerendaGraficzna(`in`)
        }

        override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<KwerendaGraficzna!> {
            return arrayOfNulls<KwerendaGraficzna!>(size)
        }
    }
}
```

`arrayOfNulls` won't compile requires `KwerendaGraficzna` while it claims it received `KwerendaGraficzna?`

So how do I do it?

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33551972/is-there-a-convenient-way-to-create-parcelable-data-classes-in-android-with-kotl

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I suspect you're using an outdated version of Kotlin compiler (since you use `!`). Here's a version compiling properly with latest version:

```
companion object {
    @JvmField
    val CREATOR = object : Parcelable.Creator<KwerendaGraficzna> {
        override fun createFromParcel(`in`: Parcel): KwerendaGraficzna {
            return KwerendaGraficzna(`in`)
        }

        override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<KwerendaGraficzna?> {
            return arrayOfNulls(size)
        }
    }
}
```

Since the `Parcelable.Creator` requires a public static field we need to mark the `CREATOR` property with [`@JvmField`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-jvm-field/) and [`JvmStatic`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-jvm-static/).

Comment: Thanx, I will check it later. One question though - why does Kotlin require type specification where Java doesn't?

Comment: @ssuukk Not sure what you mean. Kotlin uses [declaration-site variance](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#declaration-site-variance) as opposed to use-site variance.

Comment: @miensol do you think this still works? I end up with a exception:  Parcelable protocol requires a Parcelable.Creator object called CREATOR when trying to read from a bundle.

Comment: @miensol thanks! Ended up asking a question and getting it answered here. Worth noting you only need the JvmField annotation for the CREATOR.

Comment: @Eggman87 Just looked at the generated class and you're right. However it seems strange that the compiler generates a static field even though we did not instruct it to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to implement all the boilerplate code.

Instead,

```
@Parcelize
data class KwerendaGraficzna(val a: Int, val b: String): Parcelable{
    // TODO: others code
}
```

That's it.

You need to enable `experimental` to `true` in `build.gradle` to apply the method above.

```
android{
    compileSdkVersion 30
    
    defaultConfig{
        applicationId "com.example"
        minSdkVersion 25
        targetSdkVersion 30
        ...
    }

    ...

    androidExtensions {
        experimental = true
    }
}
```