# Kotlin parcelable class throwing ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android-intent, kotlin, parcelable

I have a class that I use as my data model for a `RecyclerView`in order to pass object of this class from one activity to another via `Intent` I had to make it `Parcelable`

The problem is now that I am being able to send the object from one activity to another and retrieve it, **so that the app does not crash**, but keeps throwing `ClassNotFoundException` in the logcat screen.

What am I doing wrong?

**----> Person.kt**

```
@Parcelize
class Person(var name: String, var username: String, var address: String, val avatar: Int) : Parcelable
```

**----> in MainActivity.kt**

```
val intent = Intent(this, ProfilePage::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("clicked_person",person)
        startActivity(intent)
```

**---->. `onCreate()` in ProfilePAge.kt**

```
var person  = intent.getParcelableExtra<Person>("clicked_person") as Person
```

And the `Exception`

```
E/Parcel: Class not found when unmarshalling: com.example.testkot.kotlinapp.Person
                                         java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.testkot.kotlinapp.Person
```

Please remember that the app does not crash, it keeps working but shows the exception in logcat

Comment: Where is the exception being thrown? Please show the entire stack trace? Do you put this `Intent` with "extras" in a `Notification` or send it to `AlarmManager`?

Comment: please refer this ans
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33551972/is-there-a-convenient-way-to-create-parcelable-data-classes-in-android-with-kotl

Comment: have you tried putting person object in bundle and then putting this bundle in intent extra?

Comment: @KuLdipPaTel if you check my code for `Person.kt` it matches the accepted answer you are referring to in your comment

Comment: @MalwinderSingh is it any major difference using `Bundle` or passing the parameter as I am doing on `MainActivity.kt`??

Comment: Well, I do not know why, but using a `Bundle` for sending the `Parcelable` still works and does NOT throw any exception

Answer (score 25, accepted):

After testing a solution in a comment, the following works without throwing any exception

**Sending the`Parcelable` via `Bundle`**

```
val intent = Intent(this, ProfilePage::class.java)
var bundle = Bundle()
bundle.putParcelable("selected_person",person)
intent.putExtra("myBundle",bundle)
startActivity(intent)
```

**Recovering `Parcelable`**

```
val bundle = intent.getBundleExtra("myBundle")
var person  = bundle.getParcelable<Person>("selected_person") as Person
```

However, I do not know the difference with my old code in the question and why that old code throws Exception and why this new one does not throw

Comment: No idea neither why it's working but your solution make it work. Thanks.

Comment: I second that... this worked. For some reason when you use Intent.putExtra(CustomParcellableClass) it doesn't store the classloader information.  Anyways thank you for the solution :D

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to recover the Parcelable from the savedInstanceState, but adding the line `as MyClass` did the trick.  Oddly the type arguments within the angle brackets generate a warning saying that it's unnecessary and can be inferred.  If I remove that, I get a compile error saying that the inference fails.  Make up your mind, kotlin!

Answer (score 5):

I've prepared the extension functions below for your convenience to use the Kotlin Parcelables without any warnings.

```
fun Intent.putParcel(key: String = "parcel_key", parcel: Parcelable) {
    val bundle = Bundle()
    bundle.putParcelable(key, parcel)
    this.putExtra("parcel_bundle", bundle)
}

fun <T : Parcelable> Intent.getParcel(key: String = "parcel_key"): T? {
    return this.getBundleExtra("parcel_bundle")?.getParcelable(key)
}
```

Usage:

```
//Put parcel
intent.putParcel(parcel = Person()) //any Parcalable

//Get parcel
val person: Person?  = intent.getParcel() //auto converts using Generics
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess this is a compatibility issue between Kotlin and Java for the moment.
I found an easy solution that allows using only Kotlin and without boilerplate.

```
val intent = Intent(this, ProfilePage::class.java).apply {
    extras?.putParcellable("clicked_person",person)
}

startActivity(intent)
```

And then to retrieve the value you should use:

```
var person = intent?.extras?.getParcellable<Person>("clicked_person")
```

NB: you don't need to cast as Person

Answer (score 1):

For anyone reading this in 2022, starting from Android Tiramisu(API 33) `getParcellable<Any>` has been deprecated and we've to use `getParcelable(@Nullable String key, @NonNull Class<T> clazz)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var bundle = intent.extras
var person = bundle.getParcelable<Person>("selected_person")
```

The above code is working for me. You can cut short the code as follows.

```
var person = intent.extras.getParcelable<Person>("selected_person")
```

Answer (score 0):

**In the first Activity:**

```
 val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, DetailsActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra(Const.SELECTED_NOTE, noteList[position])
        startActivity(intent)
```

**In the Second Activity:**

```
val note = intent.getParcelableExtra<Note>(Const.SELECTED_NOTE)
```

**EXPLAIN**: First you should Put `Parcelable` Data and call `getParcelableExtra` in next activity!
in `getParcelableExtra` you should call `Data class` (here is **Note** ) and `Key Of Bundle` (here is **Const.SELECTED_NOTE**)!