# Passing parcelized Kotlin data class from activity to activity does not persits data

Tags: android, kotlin, parcelable

I tried to pass a class between activities using parcelize. For this I got A class which has other classes as members:

```
@Parcelize
class Entry(var uid_sensor: String = "No-Id", val firstConfig: fConfig= fConfig(), val SecondConfig: sConfig = sConfig(),
   ...) : Parcelable { ... }
```

where e. g. `fConfig` is given by

```
@Parcelize
data class fConfig(val swVersion: UInt8 = UInt8("swStructVersion" ), val fwVersion: UInt32 = UInt32("fwVersion"),
    ...) : ConfigStructure(), Parcelable { ... }
```

and `UInt8`, `UInt32` are as well custom classes, e. g.:

```
@Parcelize
data class UInt8(override val name: String,  override val size: Int = 1, override val readOnly: Boolean = true) : DataField, Parcelable {
    var value: UByte? = 0.toUByte() // Here we init the value with zeros.
    ... // Some more parameters
}

@Parcelize
data class UInt32(override val name: String, override val size: Int = 1, override val readOnly: Boolean = true) : DataField, Parcelable {
    var value: UInt? = 0.toUInt() // Here we init the value with zeros.
    ... // Some more parameters
}
```

*Note, that these classes are initialized with zeros!*

---

Although I've marked each of this class as parcelable, I cannot pass the object correctly. If I try to return a `Entry`-Object from an Activity to the MainActivity like this

```
val returnIntent = Intent()
returnIntent.putExtra(Constants.ActivityDataPassing.SENSOR, newEntry)
setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent)
finish()
```

and capture it in the MainActivity like this:

```
val intentLauncher =
        registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->

            if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                val sen : SensorEntry = result.data?.extras?.getParcelable<Entry>(Constants.ActivityDataPassing.SENSOR) as Entry
                sensor_list?.add(sen)
                ...
            }
        }
```

the members of the classes `firstConfig` and `secondConfig` have zeros instead the values I have set. Why is this and why are my data not passed correctly? Is there a better way to share such objects between activities?

---

To make this behavior more clear, I've appended a screenshot of the very same object before and after passing.
[image: Illustration]

Comment: Hello, you could try as describe in the solution for this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46728857/kotlin-parcelable-class-throwing-classnotfoundexception

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see how this can help me? I neither run into any exception nor do I see a major difference from my approach with passing objects. If I'm wrong please correct me, since I'm now to Android and Kotlin.

Comment: well it says it had an issue passing directly the class, but if you wrap it inside a bundle, did you try it ?

Comment: val returnIntent = Intent()
var bundle = Bundle()
bundle.putParcelable(Constants.ActivityDataPassing.SENSOR, newEntry)
returnIntent.putExtra("myBundle",bundle)
setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent)
finish()

Comment: I already found out what my issue was. I have added a solution, maybe this saves someone time! But thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From - [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/parcelize)

> @Parcelize requires all serialized properties to be declared in the primary constructor. The plugin issues a warning on each property with a backing field declared in the class body. Also, you can't apply @Parcelize if some of the primary constructor parameters are not properties.

Therefore, this fixes it:

```
@Parcelize
data class UInt32(
   override val name: String, 
   override val size: Int = 1, 
   override val readOnly: Boolean = true, 
   var value: UInt? = 0.toUInt()
) : DataField, Parcelable {
     // Here we init the value with zeros.
    ... // Some more parameters
}
```