# How to Pass custom object via intent in kotlin

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

```
fun launchNextScreen(context: Context, people: People): Intent {
    val intent = Intent(context, NextScreenActivity::class.java)
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_PEOPLE, (Parcelable) people)
    //intent.putExtra(EXTRA_PEOPLE, people as Parcelable)
    //intent.putExtra(EXTRA_PEOPLE, people)
    // tried above all three ways
    return intent
}
```

I tried the above code to pass an instance of the `People` class via intent using kotlin, but I am getting an error.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

First, make sure the `People` class implements the `Serializable` interface:

```
class People : Serializable {
    // your stuff
}
```

Inner fields of `People` class must also implement the `Serializable` interface, otherwise you'll get runtime error.

Then it should work:

```
fun launchNextScreen(context: Context, people: People): Intent {
    val intent = Intent(context, NextScreenActivity::class.java)
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_PEOPLE, people)
    return intent
}
```

To receive people back from Intent you'll need to call:

```
val people = intent.getSerializableExtra(EXTRA_PEOPLE) as? People
```

Comment: how to get the serializable class in other activity?

Comment: @VikashParajuli in the context of this example you'll need to call
`val people = getIntent().getExtras().getSerializableExtra(EXTRA_PEOPLE) as? People`

Comment: its slower, you need to use Parcelable for better performance

Comment: @a2en that's something that everybody is saying, but nobody knows for sure) on small objects you would not see any difference. 
However, there is a way to make Serializable faster than Parcelable, for more information see Farhana answer in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323074/android-difference-between-parcelable-and-serializable

Answer (score 44):

Implement Serializable in the object:

```
data class Object (
        var param1: Int? = null,
        var param2: String? = null
) : Serializable
```

or

```
class Object : Serializable {
        var param1: Int? = null,
        var param2: String? = null
}
```

Then, you can pass the object using Intent:

```
val object = Object()
...
val intent = Intent(this, Activity2::class.java)
intent.putExtra("extra_object", object as Serializable)
startActivity(intent)
```

Finally, in Activity2 you get the object with:

```
val object = intent.extras.get("extra_object") as Object
```

Answer (score 25):

Found a better way of doing this:

In your gradle:

```html
apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.extensions'

android {
    androidExtensions {
        experimental = true
    }
}
```

In your data class:

```kotlin
@Parcelize
data class Student(val id: String, val name: String, val grade: String) : Parcelable
```

In source activity:

```
val intent = Intent(context, Destination::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("student_id", student)
        context.startActivity(intent)
```

In destination activity:

```kotlin
student = intent.getParcelableExtra("student_id")
```

Comment: This works but you have to set this in your build.gradle: apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.extensions'

android {
    androidExtensions {
        experimental = true
    }
}

Answer (score 25):

### `Parcelize` is no longer experimental, as of Kotlin **1.3.60+**!

Define a data class, adding `@Parcelize` annotation and extending `Parcelable`:

```
@Parcelize
data class People(val id: String, val name: String) : Parcelable
```

To add to intent:

```kotlin
val intent = Intent(context, MyTargetActivity::class.java)
intent.putExtra("people_data", student)
context.startActivity(intent)
```

In `MyTargetActivity`:

```
val people: People = intent.getParcelableExtra("people_data")
```

If you haven't yet, enable extensions in your app's `build.gradle`. This also enables [data binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding) and [other great advanced features](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html)

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

Comment: the solution more clean and simple.

Comment: `kotlin-android-extensions` is now deprecated, you should use `kotlin-parcelize` plugin for [Parcelable implementation generator](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/parcelize).

Answer (score 9):

I found a better way to pass an object from one activity to another using Parcelable, it is faster than Serialization
[Android: Difference between Parcelable and Serializable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323074/android-difference-between-parcelable-and-serializable)

first, add these lines of code inside build.gradle(app)

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions' in app.grable 

@Parcelize 
class Model(val title: String, val amount: Int) : Parcelable
```

**passing with Intent--->**

```
val intent = Intent(this, DetailActivity::class.java)
intent.putExtra(DetailActivity.EXTRA, model)
startActivity(intent)
```

**Getting from intent --->**

```
val model: Model = intent.getParcelableExtra(EXTRA)
```

Comment: Good news!! its not experimental anymore

Comment: that's something that everybody is saying, but nobody knows for sure) on small objects you would not see any difference. Also, nice to have this Kotlin sugar, but what about good old java? 
However, there is a way to make Serializable faster than Parcelable, for more information see Farhana answer in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323074/android-difference-between-parcelable-and-serializable

Comment: getParcelableExtra & getSerializable both are deprecated

Answer (score 3):

This post might be useful for what you intend to do:

[Is there a convenient way to create Parcelable data classes in Android with Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33551972/is-there-a-convenient-way-to-create-parcelable-data-classes-in-android-with-kotl)

Basically, kotlin provides some little extras:

```
@Parcelize
class User(val firstName: String, val lastName: String) : Parcelable
```

See the post for more info.

Answer (score 0):

in kotlin to start activity and pass some data you could try something like this:

`startActivity(intentFor<NameOfActivity>(STRING to data))`

**Have Fun**

Comment: and how to receive data in another class?

Answer (score 0):

you have to add the type inside <>...its working for me

val people = intent.getParcelableExtra<*People*>(EXTRA_PEOPLE) as People

In your PeopleDetailActivity activity, initialize viewModel in onCreate

```
viewModel = this@PeopleDetailActivity.viewModel.apply { postPeopleId(getPeopleFromIntent().id) }
```

And also initialize this method :

```
private fun getPeopleFromIntent() = intent.getParcelableExtra<People>(peopleId) as People
```

Write below code for passing the intent extras :

```
companion object {
        private const val objectId = "people"
        fun startActivityModel(context: Context?, people: People) {
            if (context != null) {
                val intent = Intent(context, PeopleDetailActivity::class.java).apply {
                    putExtra(
                        objectId,
                        people
                    )
                }
                context.startActivity(intent)
            }
        }
    }
```

Call the above method in your PeopleListViewHolder onClick

```
override fun onClick(v: View?) = PeopleDetailActivity.startActivityModel(context(), people)
```

Comment: This will just work if the custom object is parcable. Would be great if you provide some sample Code.

Comment: edited the answer with an example @MarcelHofgesang

Answer (score 0):

Code for linking the two activities and passing name to second activity
MainActivity.kt

```
val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)

    button.setOnClickListener() {
        val name = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editText)
        val message = name.text.toString()

        intent = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("EXTRA MESSAGE", message)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
```

Main.xml

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="Click"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:text="Name"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

secondactivity.kt

```
 val message = intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA MESSAGE")
    val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView2).apply {
        text = message
    }


    Toast.makeText(this, "Name is : $message",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    val button2 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button2)
    button2.setOnClickListener(){
        intent = Intent(this,MainActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
```

second.xml

```
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="SecondActivity"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.345" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="back"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.774" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Your People class needs to implement Parcelable like this:

```
class People(): Parcelable{
// stuff


}
```

android studio will show you an error. Simple move your cursor to "People" and hit alt+enter. It should now show the option to generate a Parcelable implementation.

This generated code will contain something like

```
parcel.writeString(member1)
parcel.writeInt(member2)
```

and somewhere else

```
member1=parcel.readString()
member2=parcel.readInt()
```

Make sure that  all members are contained in these methods and when modifying it, make sure that read and write is happening in the exact same order.