# Can I press a button in Activity A to filter a RecyclerView in Activity B?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, recyclerlistview

What I want to reach is that the same `RecyclerView` shows different data depending on which button the App user pressed before in the `MainActivity.kt`.

In my `MainActivity.kt` I have two buttons, which both send the user to the same RecyclerView Activity (`RecyclerViewLayout.kt`) via Intent.

**Example**: The RecyclerView contains a picture of an apple and a banana. By pressing button A in `MainActivity.kt`, the RecyclerView in `RecyclerViewLayout.kt` should only show the apple. By pressing button B it should only show the banana. In my real app there are no fruits. but Tutorials, which should be filtered like described.

I gently ask for help here how to do that. Maybe there is also a better way to reach my target to filter the `RecyclerView`?

Thanks in Advance!

`MainActivity.kt`

```kotlin
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var binding:ActivityMainBinding? = null


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding?.root)


        val buttonRecyclerView = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn_recyclerview)
        buttonRecyclerView.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, RecyclerViewLayout::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }}
```

`RecyclerViewLayout.kt`

```kotlin
    class RecyclerViewLayout : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var newRecylerview : RecyclerView
    private lateinit var newArrayList : ArrayList<RecyclerViewDataClass>
    private lateinit var tempArrayList : ArrayList<RecyclerViewDataClass>
    lateinit var imageId : Array<Int>
    lateinit var tutorialHeading : Array<String>
    lateinit var tutorialText : Array<String>
    lateinit var url : Array<String>

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recycler_view_layout)
        imageId = arrayOf(
            R.drawable.brake,
            R.drawable.brake,
            )

        tutorialHeading = arrayOf(
            getString(R.string.scheibenbremse_lüften_heading),
            getString(R.string.felgenbremse_richten_heading),
            

        )

        tutorialText = arrayOf(

            getString(R.string.scheibenbremse_lüften_text),
            getString(R.string.felgenbremse_richten_text),
        )

        url = arrayOf(

            getString(R.string.url_a),
            getString(R.string.url_b),
        )


        newRecylerview =findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)
        newRecylerview.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        newRecylerview.setHasFixedSize(true)


        newArrayList = arrayListOf<RecyclerViewDataClass>()
        tempArrayList = arrayListOf<RecyclerViewDataClass>()
        getUserdata()

    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {

        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_item,menu)
        val item = menu?.findItem(R.id.search_action)
        val searchView = item?.actionView as SearchView
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{
            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }

            override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {

                tempArrayList.clear()
                val searchText = newText!!.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                if (searchText.isNotEmpty()){

                    newArrayList.forEach {

                        if (it.heading.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(searchText)){


                            tempArrayList.add(it)

                        }

                    }

                    newRecylerview.adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()

                }else{

                    tempArrayList.clear()
                    tempArrayList.addAll(newArrayList)
                    newRecylerview.adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()

                }


                return false

            }


        })

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }

    private fun getUserdata() {

        for(i in imageId.indices){

            val news = RecyclerViewDataClass(imageId[i],tutorialHeading[i],url[i])
            newArrayList.add(news)

        }

        tempArrayList.addAll(newArrayList)


        val adapter = RecyclerViewAdapter(tempArrayList)

        newRecylerview.adapter = adapter
        adapter.setOnItemClickListener(object : RecyclerViewAdapter.onItemClickListener{
            override fun onItemClick(position: Int) {

                val intent = Intent(this@RecyclerViewLayout,TutorialsActivity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("tutorialHeading",newArrayList[position].heading)
                intent.putExtra("imageId",newArrayList[position].titleImage)
                intent.putExtra("url",newArrayList[position].url)
                intent.putExtra("tutorialText",tutorialText[position])
                startActivity(intent)

            }


        })

    }}
```

`RecyclerViewAdapter.kt`

```kotlin
    class RecyclerViewAdapter(private val newsList : ArrayList<RecyclerViewDataClass>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder>(),
    Filterable {

    private lateinit var mListener : onItemClickListener

    interface onItemClickListener{

        fun onItemClick(position : Int)

    }

    fun setOnItemClickListener(listener: onItemClickListener){

        mListener = listener

    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {

        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.list_item,
            parent,false)

        return MyViewHolder(itemView,mListener)

    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {

        val currentItem = newsList[position]
        holder.titleImage.setImageResource(currentItem.titleImage)
        holder.tvHeading.text = currentItem.heading

    }


    override fun getItemCount(): Int {

        return newsList.size
    }

    class MyViewHolder(itemView : View, listener: onItemClickListener) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){

        val titleImage : ShapeableImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_image)
        val tvHeading : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvHeading)

        init {

            itemView.setOnClickListener {

                listener.onItemClick(adapterPosition)

            }


        }

    }

    override fun getFilter(): Filter {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }}
```

`RecyclerViewDataClass.kt`

```kotlin
    data class RecyclerViewDataClass(var titleImage: Int, var heading: String, val url: String)

**Tutorials Activity**

    class TutorialsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tutorials)

        val headingNews : TextView = findViewById(R.id.heading)
        val mainNews : TextView = findViewById(R.id.news)
        val imageNews : ImageView = findViewById(R.id.image_heading)

        val bundle : Bundle?= intent.extras
        val tutorialHeading = bundle!!.getString("tutorialHeading")
        val imageId = bundle.getInt("imageId")
        val tutorialText = bundle.getString("tutorialText")
        val url = bundle.getString("url")

        headingNews.text = tutorialHeading
        mainNews.text = tutorialText
        imageNews.setImageResource(imageId)

        imageNews.setOnClickListener {
            val openURL = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
            openURL.data = Uri.parse(url.toString())
            startActivity(openURL)
        }


    }}
```

Comment: only one activity is active at a time, you should avoid `activity a changes activity b` type of thinking. a recyclerview is managed by an adapter, an adapter has data. activity x can change that data, depending on where you store it, sure

Comment: Thank you for answering that fast sir! Can you describe how to do that in my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can pass data about which button is clicked using **intents**. Here's a link about that:
[How to Pass custom object via intent in kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47593205/how-to-pass-custom-object-via-intent-in-kotlin#47595896)

For example, you can pass "A" if button A is clicked and "B" if button B is clicked, and then get that string in **RecyclerViewLayout.kt** to determine which elements should be shown.

Answer (score 0):

According to me the simplest solution for doing this is you should have a `boolean` in `preferences` you can set `preferences` according to the button clicked and set data in your `adapter` to by getting the `preferences` value.

If you want to set data according to the button clicked

Other way is to pass the action `onClick` while starting a new `Activity` and `getAction()` in your second `Activity`.

This way you can also set data of your `recyclerView` by passing different data

Comment: boolean is not a good choice as there could be many items right? Maybe apple, banana and pear. Now, how does boolean work with this?

Comment: then you can work with strings. Otherwise if situation is like this you have many items to click and move to next activity which is with recyclerview so you can pass action with intent and get in second activity.

Comment: Boolean is for if you have only two options. If you have many options then string will work the same