# Parcelable isn't working properly in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, parcelable, data-class

I send `sendData` from `StartActivity` to `ResultActivity`.

```
val sendData = SendData(10, "xyz", "yss")
sendData.e = 933
sendData.f = "hello"
sendData.g = 39

// Log.d("A", "${sendData.toString}")
val intent = Intent(this@StartActivity, ResultActivity::class.java)
intent.putExtra(RESULT_DATA, sendData)
startActivity(intent)
```

```
sendData = intent.extras!!.getParcelable(RESULT_DATA)
// Log.d("B", "${sendData.toString}")
```

The model class looks  like this.

```
@Parcelize
data class SendData(var a: Int, var b: String, var c: String) : Parcelable {
    var e: Int? = null
    var f: String? = null
    var g: Int? = null
    
    var isClicked = false

    override fun toString(): String{
        return JsonUtil.toJson(this) // custom util
    }
}
```

But when I check the Log-A, Log-B.

```
// Log-A
{
   "a": 10,
   "b": "xyz",
   "c": "yss",
   "e": 933,
   "f": "hello",
   "g": 39,
   "isClicked": false
}

// Log-B
{
   "a": 10,
   "b": "xyz",
   "c": "yss",
   "isClicked": false
}
```

So, the members which is defined as Nullable are null after being passed.
What's the problem of this code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way that `@Parcelize` works is that it only serializes/deserializes the properties in the primary constructor. You've only declared properties `a`, `b` and `c` in the primary constructor. Therefore, the compiler will only insert the values of `a`, `b` and `c` into the generated `Parcel` and, of course, only these values will be unmarshalled at the receiving end.

You need to add the other properties to your primary constructor, or implement the `Parcelable` interface yourself instead of using `@Parcelize`.

See https://joaoalves.dev/posts/kotlin-playground/parcelable-in-kotlin-here-comes-parcelize/

See also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33551972/is-there-a-convenient-way-to-create-parcelable-data-classes-in-android-with-kotl) and the various suggestions in the answers

Answer (score 1):

> @Parcelize requires all serialized properties to be declared in the primary constructor. The plugin issues a warning on each property with a backing field declared in the class body. Also, you can't apply @Parcelize if some of the primary constructor parameters are not properties.

From https://developer.android.com/kotlin/parcelize
You must move e, f, and g variable declaration to primary constructor
Your model code can be like this:

```kotlin
@Parcelize
data class SendData(var a: Int, var b: String, var c: String, var e: Int? = null, var f: String? = null, var g: Int? = null) : Parcelable { 
    var isClicked = false

    override fun toString(): String{
        return JsonUtil.toJson(this) // custom util
    }
}
```